# Пытаюсь улучшить обработчик ошибок

Tags: python, discord.py

Код реагирования на возникшие ошибки у меня выглядит так:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(embed = TYPE_ERROR, delete_after = C)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(embed = PERM_ERROR, delete_after = C)
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(embed = NOFD_ERROR, delete_after = C)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(embed = REQA_ERROR, delete_after = C)
```

И мне он кажется крайне неуклюжим. Хотелось бы узнать каким образом можно это улучшить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соберите пары в таблицу соответствия и переберите её:

```
com_err = [
    (commands.BadArgument, TYPE_ERROR),
    (commands.MissingPermissions, PERM_ERROR),
    (commands.CommandNotFound, NOFD_ERROR),
    (commands.MissingRequiredArgument, REQA_ERROR)
]

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    for com, err in com_err:
        if isinstance(error, com):
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send(embed = err, delete_after = C)
```